# Fontawesome: How to control height and width of stacked icons

Tags: css, font-awesome

I am trying to inline stacked icons in a row which is doubling the width and height of stacked icons.

```
<div class="large">
    Fl<span class="fa-stack" style="width: 13vw; vertical-align: middle"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x round"></i><i class='fa fa-lightbulb-o bulb fa-stack-1x'></i></span>ating
    <br/>R<i class='fa fa-circle round'></i>und <br/>Butt<i class='fa fa-circle round'></i>n
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.large{
    color: #6a9ca7;
    font-size: 13vw;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-align: center; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

So if the height of an icon is 169px then after stacking it becomes 338px. How can I solve it?

I somehow controlled the width spacing by setting width to 13vw explicitly. But this hack is not working on height.

Here is the [example](https://naturalintelligence.github.io/floating-round-button/).

Comment: is that your ".large" class contains "with:13vw;" rule?

Comment: Yes, updated the question

Comment: when the height of an icons be "169px". Zoom in ?

Comment: Since the font size is set to 13vw, icon size reaches to 169px on desktop. You can check the attached sample link.

Comment: i checked the link above but i could not understand what is the problem. everything looks fine

Comment: if you notice the distance between "Floating" and "Round" is more than the distance between "Round" and "Button" words. Now if you inspect element, you'll see that it is because of the height of stacked icon which is double than expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add these rules to stack style class

```
height: 13vw;vertical-align: super;
```

your code will look like this

```
<div class="large">
Fl<span class="fa-stack" style="width: 13vw; height:13vw; vertical-align: super;"><i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-1x round"></i><i class='fa fa-lightbulb-o bulb fa-stack-1x'></i></span>ating
<br/>R<i class='fa fa-circle round'></i>und <br/>Butt<i class='fa fa-circle round'></i>n
```

Comment: Wow, grt it worked. However I was wondering if fontawesome handle such case gracefully instead of hacks.

Comment: Yes,you are right. I am wondering too :) it looks like their mistake. :)